# Fuzzy string matching and regex

Tags: regex, r, string-matching, fuzzy-comparison

I have a vector of sentences such as:

```
example <- c("text text word1 text text word2 text text", ...)
```

and I'm trying to identify which sentences comply with the following rules:

- the sentence contains both "word1" and "word2"
- "word1" comes before "word2"
- there are between zero and three words between "word1" and "word2"

This could be done with a normal regex. However, the problem is that "word1" or "word2" can contain typos (I am expecting at most a distance of 3 for both words together). Examples of typos could be "wrod1", "woord2", "wrd1", etc. I also want to match the sentences that contain typos for these words within the distance constraint. Therefore I was trying to use `agrepl`:

```
agrepl("(?:.*?)\\bword1\\b(?:\\s(?:\\w+\\s){0,3})\\bword2\\b(?:.*?)", example, fixed=FALSE, max=3)
```

However, I believe that the distance is being calculated with the whole sentence and not only with "word1" and "word2", and therefore I will almost never get any matches in this way. Any suggestions on how to fix this, or is agrepl/regex not the best tool for this problem?

Comment: I see a big issue here with the typo disambiguation. How can one be sure `woord2` is not `coord2`? How can we identify `word` instances? A possible solution would be, perhaps, extracting pairs of words from the string at certain places and check them with `adist`.

Comment: In this case, it would still be useful for me if the match returned `TRUE` since I am interested in the context of the sentence. Meaning, the relevant information that I need to extract from this is the fact that "word2" came after "word1" (with or without typos for either) for this sentence, and respecting the other constraints.

Comment: This may be a laddish comment but maybe it would be worthwhile to consider breaking the sentence into words and evaluating expression on each word, this would solve the computational issues surrounding undesired distance calculation for the whole sentence. You could then evaluate the mid-level objects to see how many words spelled correctly or misspelled were matched and then, depending on the applied criteria, merge it back to one sentence when desired.

Comment: What if you assume that a word is the same word with typos if it starts and ends with the same character, but has the inner characters in any amounts and order? Like `agrepl("\\bw[or]+d\\d+\\b(?:\\S+\\s+){0,3}\\s+w[or]+d\\d+", example, fixed=FALSE, max=3)`?

Answer (score 2):

This fit for your rules, however I'm not sure what would your typos looks like. If you could show some example, it would be great.

`^(?=.*word1\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,3}word2.*$).*`
[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zF7gY6/2)

Comment: Yes, this matches the sentence provided that it has no typos. I'd still have to solve the main problem though, which is dealing with misspellings for word1 or word2. Added more info on the post.

Comment: There are some issues with this approach: the regex requires `perl=T` (this is not supported by `agrep`) and the `.` does not match a newline in a PCRE regex.